# JTable object [][] data

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I am trying to create a table based on my trial class. When I try to run my table class the table prints with the proper heading, but it does not print anything in the body of the table. How should I fix my for loop so the data enters the table? Do I need to add a parameter to the constructor?

I understand there are more getters and setters than necessary. I was just trying to go about the for loop in different ways.

```
public class Trial extends JFrame{

static int counter = 0;
int laps = 0;
String lapTime;
double currentTime = 0;
String difference;
int lapsCount = 0;
String[] array1;
double[] array2;
double[] array3;

 public int getLapsCount() {
    return lapsCount;
}

public void setLapsCount(int lapsCount) {
    this.lapsCount = lapsCount;
}

public static int getCounter() {
    return counter;
}

public static void setCounter(int counter) {
    Trial.counter = counter;
}

public int getLaps() {
    return laps;
}

public void setLaps(int laps) {
    this.laps = laps;
}

public String getLapTime() {
    return lapTime;
}

public void setLapTime(String lapTime) {
    this.lapTime = lapTime;
}

public double getCurrentTime() {
    return currentTime;
}

public void setCurrentTime(double currentTime) {
    this.currentTime = currentTime;
}

public String getDifference() {
    return difference;
}

public void setDifference(String difference) {
    this.difference = difference;
}

public String[] getArray1() {
    return array1;
}

public void setArray1(String[] array1) {
    this.array1 = array1;
}

public double[] getArray2() {
    return array2;
}

public void setArray2(double[] array2) {
    this.array2 = array2;
}

public double[] getArray3() {
    return array3;
}

public void setArray3(double[] array3) {
    this.array3 = array3;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //drop down for number of laps
     String lapsString;
     String[] selections = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};
        lapsString = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                                                      "Choose a number of laps:",
                                                      "Lap Counter",
                                                      JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
                                                      null, /* icon */
                                                      selections,
                                                      "0");
        System.out.printf("Number of laps = \"%s\"\n", lapsString);

    int lapsCount = Integer.parseInt(lapsString);
    String[] array1 = new String[lapsCount+1];
    double[] array2 = new double[lapsCount+1];
    double[] array3 = new double[lapsCount+1];

    // showInputDialog with for lap time
    for (int i = 1; i <= lapsCount; i++){
        String lapTime;
        lapTime = 
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter lap " + i + " total time.");
        System.out.printf("Lap " + i + " = \"%s\"\n", lapTime);
        array1[i] = lapTime;
        double currentTime = inputConvert(array1[i]);
        array2[i] = currentTime;
        array3[i] = (array2[i] - array2[i-1]);
        counter++;

        //confirm each time 
            int result;
            String[] results = { "Yes", "No", "Cancel" };

            result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                                           "Please confirm lap " + i + " is " + lapTime);
            if (result == -1)
                System.out.printf("user closed window\n");
            else if (result == 0)
                System.out.printf("result = %d, user pressed \"%s\"\n", result, results[result]);
            else {
                lapTime = 
                        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please re-enter lap " + i);
                System.out.printf("Lap " + i + " = \"%s\"\n", lapTime);
                counter++;
        }
    }
}

    public static double inputConvert(String s) {
        double convert = 0.0;
        int minutes = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 1));
        double seconds = Double.parseDouble(s.substring(2, s.length()));
        minutes = minutes * 60;
        convert = minutes + seconds;
        return convert;

    }

    private static String getDifference(int j, double sign) {
        String difference = "";
        if(j == 0) {
            difference = "---";
        }
        else if(sign > 0.0) {
            difference = "+";
        }
        return difference;
    }

    public static String displayTime(double time) {
        String result = null;
        int minutes = (int) (time/60);
        double seconds = (time % 60);
        seconds = Math.round(seconds*100.0)/100.0;
        if(seconds < 10){
            result = minutes + ":0" + seconds;  
        }
        else{
            result = minutes + ":" + seconds;   
        }

        return result;
    }
 }
```

This is my table class where the problem arises.

```
public class table { 

public static void main(String[] args) { 

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
        @Override 
        public void run() { 
            new table(); 
            } 
        }); 
}

public table() { 
    JFrame guiFrame = new JFrame(); 

    guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    guiFrame.setTitle("Table to record lap times"); 
    guiFrame.setSize(700,200); 

    guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 

    JTable table = new JTable(new ExampleTableModel()); 

    table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true); 

    table.setGridColor(Color.YELLOW); 
    table.setBackground(Color.CYAN); 

    JScrollPane tableScrollPane = new JScrollPane(table); 

    guiFrame.add(tableScrollPane); 
    guiFrame.setVisible(true); 

} 


class ExampleTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{ 

    int laps = 0;
    String lapTime;
    double currentTime = 0;
    String difference;

    Trial t = new Trial();

     //Two arrays used for the table data 
    private String[] columnNames = {"Lap #", "Total Time", "Lap Time" , "Difference" };
    private Object[][] data;

    public ExampleTableModel(){

        data = new Object[laps][4];
        for(int i = 0; i < laps; i++){
            data[i][0] = "Lap " + i;
            data[i][1] = t.getArray1() [i]; 
            data[i][2] = t.getArray2()[i]; 
            data[i][3] = t.getArray3()[i]; 
        }
    }

    @Override public int getRowCount() { 
        return data.length; 
        } 

    @Override public int getColumnCount() { 
        return columnNames.length; 
        } 

    @Override public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) { 
        return data[row][column]; 
        } 


    @Override public String getColumnName(int column) { 
        return columnNames[column]; 
        } 

    @Override public Class getColumnClass(int c) { 
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass(); 
        } 

    @Override public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) { 
        if (column == 0 || column == 1) { 
            return false; 
            } 
        else { 
            return true; 
        } 
      } 
    }
  }
```

I made those changes but I need my output to look like this 
Lap #:  Total time  Lap time    Difference
Lap1:   2:10        2:10        ---

I fixed the lap number so it starts at 1. I made these changes in the hopes that it would fix the lap time and difference cells but it is giving me an error.

public ExampleTableModel(Trial trial){

```
        int laps = trial.getLapsCount();
        data = new Object[laps][4];
        for(int i = 0; i < laps; i++){
            if (i == 0){
                data[i][0] = "Lap " + (i + 1);
                data[i][1] = trial.getArray1() [i + 1]; 
                data[i][2] = trial.getArray2() [i + 1]; 
                data[i][3] = trial.getDifference(i, (trial.getArray3()[i + 1] - trial.getArray3()[i]));
            }

            else {
                data[i][0] = "Lap " + (i + 1);
                data[i][1] = trial.getArray1() [i + 1]; 
                data[i][2] = trial.displayTime(trial.getArray2() [i + 1] - trial.getArray2() [i]); 
                data[i][3] = trial.getDifference(i, (trial.getArray3()[i + 1] - trial.getArray3()[i])) + (trial.getArray3()[i + 1] - trial.getArray3()[i]);

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: combining the code from the `Trial.main` and the `Table.main` methods**

To make the code from your `Trial` class easier to use from the `Table` class, you can make the following changes. This way you can create a `Trial` object and call the `getUserInput` to let the user initialize it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Trial().getUserInput();
}

public void getUserInput() {
    // [Code from the old main method...]

    // Use the fields of the class instead of local variables:
    lapsCount = Integer.parseInt(lapsString);
    array1 = new String[lapsCount+1];
    array2 = new double[lapsCount+1];
    array3 = new double[lapsCount+1];

    // [Code from the old main method...]
}
```

Now you can modify the `Table` model like this:

```
public Table() {
    // [...]

    Trial trial = new Trial();
    trial.getUserInput();
    JTable table = new JTable(new ExampleTableModel(trial));

    // [...]
}
```

And let the `ExampleTableModel` constructor use a `trail` parameter (the `laps` and `t` fields are no longer used):

```
public ExampleTableModel(Trial trial){
    int laps = trial.getLapsCount();
    data = new Object[laps][4];
    for(int i = 0; i < laps; i++){
        data[i][0] = "Lap " + i;
        data[i][1] = trial.getArray1()[i];
        data[i][2] = trial.getArray2()[i];
        data[i][3] = trial.getArray3()[i];
    }
}
```

There was also an issue with the `getColumnClass` method:

```
@Override public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
    //return  getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
    return (column <= 1) ? String.class : Double.class;
}
```

Now the table looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of table]

The output was:

```
Number of laps = "2"
Lap 1 = "2:10"
result = 0, user pressed "Yes"
Lap 2 = "2:20"
result = 0, user pressed "Yes"
```

**Old answer**

There seem to be a few issues that prevent the table from being filled:

In the `ExampleTableModel` class the `laps` field should be something higher than zero (for the constructor to fill the `data` array):

```
class ExampleTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    //int laps = 0;
    int laps = 6;
```

In the constructor of the `ExampleTableModel` class:

```
        public ExampleTableModel(){

            data = new Object[laps][4];
            for(int i = 0; i < laps; i++){
                data[i][0] = "Lap " + i;
                data[i][1] = t.getArray1()[i];
                data[i][2] = t.getArray2()[i];
                data[i][3] = t.getArray3()[i];
            }
        }
```

the calls to the `t.getArray1`, `t.getArray2`, and `t.getArray3` methods return `null`. The `Trial` object appears to have no data yet.

Do you want your program to execute both the code of the `Trial.main` method and the `Table.main` method?

Comment: should i add this constructor to the trial class?                                     public Trial(String[] array1, double[] array2, double[] array3, int lapsCount) {
   this.array1 = array1;
   this.array2 = array2;
   this.array3 = array3;
   this.lapsCount = lapsCount;
 }                                                                                                       and then change laps to t.getLapsCount?

Comment: Yes I want to execute both codes. I just separated them now because the trial class runs properly and the table class is not